# Magento: StoreView URL redirect for multiple languages?

Tags: magento

In my store I have got 2 languages, `English (default)` and `German`. I also have a category, lets call it `other`.

The url key for `other` is `other` and `sonstiges` for the German view. Now, when I send somebody a link to the German view (www.example.com/sonstiges.html), it generates a 404 not found until I select German as language. Afterwards it works when the link is clicked.

I removed the store view code from my url by the way, it has to stay that way.

Why is that and how can I change it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its happening for url rewrite problem. 
Example : For product if you provide different url key for different store view like different url key for English and different url key for German then if you share the url from english site and if someone open in German view then he will get 404 not found.

Solution : Go to that particular product in the admin then switch store view and set same url key for both store view. Either dont provide url key for any store view so Magento will generate by own.

Thanks .